How can I give alternate numbered distance in a 2D array in Geometry Nodes?
So it's basically a 2D array. 3 rows 9 columns as shown in photo attached. Each column has fixed width e.g., N millimeters (marked by yellow arrows).
However, what I want is, each gap between the columns should have alternative distance. E.g., if first distance is N, the next should be N + 2 millimeters. Then again N, then N + 2 and so on (illustrated in 2nd photo).
I tried several Math nodes including Floored modulo but I just couldn't do it. I'm not good at Maths. I asked in some forums/discord but nothing worked for me.
Basically I need to control the X offset value (which is 5 currently). And make it alternative on each column Array instance.
But I think it should have an easy solution which I'm unable to find. So is it possible to do it with nodes?



An easy way would be to take the distance between the 1st and 3rd element, call it $a$, then space elements evenly by $a \over 2$, so that odd elements are positioned properly, and now shift the even elements to the left by $a - b$, where $b$ is the desired spacing:


Nice. That's indeed easier way as I expected, but I don't have much experience so I couldn't even think like that. It worked for me, I just had to add one more Set Position node and minor adjustments for it to work on 2D arrays as well.
